# Dynamically set and un-set event listeners in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, delegates

I have used obj c delegates a couple of times and know their basic use. But I have the following problem:

I use the Dropbox SDK for iOS and use their builtin delegate method for DeltaEntriesLoaded. But I use it from two different positions in my code. From the first position I want to do my "normal stuff" but from the second position I want as soon as the delta entries are loaded to access an array filled by this DeltaEntries method.

So, I have a class which calls LoadDelta but, depending on when it is calling it, it needs to have a different behavior right after the DeltaEntries are loaded. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem that only one object can be declared as the delegate on which `deltaEntriesLoaded` will be called, but you need it to be called in more than one place?

It might be a good idea to create an intermediate object that interacts with the DropboxSDK.  For example, you might have a DropboxManager singleton object that serves as the delegate.  The DropboxManager will have an array of DropboxManagerListeners - the objects in your code that need to be notified when the delta entries are loaded.  The DropboxManager will then loop through the listeners and call `deltaEntriesLoaded` on each listener, to notify them.

The **pseudocode** would be:

DropboxManager.h

```
@protocol DropboxManagerListener <NSObject>

- (void)deltaEntriesLoaded:(NSArray *)deltaEntries;

@end

@interface DropboxManager : NSObject

+ (DropboxManager *)sharedManager

- (void)addListener:(id<DropboxManagerListener *>) listener;

@end
```

DropboxManager.m

```
@interface DropboxManager () <DropboxDelegate>

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray<DeltaManagerListener *> *listeners;

@end

@implementation

+ (DropboxManager *)sharedManager {
    static DropboxManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
        //set sharedManager as the DropboxSDKDelegate here
    });
    return sharedManager;
}

- (void)addListener:(id<DropboxManagerListener *>)listener {
    self.listeners = //code to do self.listeners + listener
}

- (void)deltaEntriesLoaded:(NSArray *)deltaEntries { //Delegate method from Dropbox SDK 
    for id<DeltaManagerListener *> listener in self.listeners {
         [listener deltaEntriesLoaded:deltaEntries];
    }
}

@end
```

So when you need an object to be notified of the `deltaEntriesLoaded`, just make sure they adhere to the DropboxManagerListener protocol and add themselves as a listener by calling `[[DropboxManager sharedManager] addListener:yourObject];`

It's nice to separate out any code dealing with a third party into one single class and have other code interact with the intermediate class.  This way, if you ever end up needing to switch to a different third party, you might not have to change as much code.